# Chamfering with a conical bit makes a table drill vibrate

Tags: steel, drilling

I have a slow-speed drill press which seems quite solid, the play is minimal. Normally, it does not cause problems. This conical bit:

[image: conical bit]

when applied to this 8 mm hole:

[image]

is an exception: the bit jumps and squeaks loudly, the machine resonates. As seen in the image, it is impossible to make an even chamfer. I was thinking about filling the hole with a 3d-printed plastic cylinder with a small pilot hole, but I am not sure it it would help, given that the material is a hard stainless steel. It is fastened in a 4.5 kg vice which can move freely, so that the bit position can be adjusted. The vice seems to be stable, despite the vibration.

How to make an even chamfer? Its angle of 45 deg is important.

Comment: Could you show an image of the vice, and the drilling bit with the drill. I would like to see how is it held. Is it hand held or do you use a fixture to drive in the drill bit

Comment: I used the vice Draper 64585 and a medium-size table drill press with a crank, on a steel column of a 5 cm diameter. It is a typical consumer-grade drill press with an asynchronous motor.

Comment: There is only one solution to this for SS, use a step bit.

Comment: https://ekstromcarlson.com/wp-content/uploads/KUB-Drillmax-Special-1-Step-Drill.pdf

Comment: A step drill will not produce a clean countersunk profile. (But step drills are certainly very useful tools for drilling large diameter holes in thin material).

Comment: Just looks like chatter to me, have you tried a single flute countersink bit?

Comment: @alephzero there are different kinds of step bits. The multistep electrical panel box drill isn't what I'm talking about.

Comment: @PhilSweet The M8 two-step bits which I have seen have a piloting part of 9mm, here the hole is 8 mm.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Are there any single-flute countersink bits for hard metals?

Comment: ...yes? Any hardened tool steel is harder than stainless? You can get them with e.g. Ti coating, but it shouldn't be necessary. This is the set I have, which I've never had a problem with. https://www.toolstation.com/hss-countersink-set/p18880

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I suspect his drill press isn't heavy enough to stop the chatter. The table or head is flexing vertically. Those are the proper tools alright, if you have a heavy enough drill press. A step bit is far more expensive than those, but far less expensive than a heavy duty press. Having used and abused crappy shop tools at work for 30 years, I'd probably try to jam a pipe leg under the table just to see if it helps. We don't know how many of these he has to do in a week - 100, or 10,000

Comment: It is just one series, but I need precision. I'll test how the one-flute bits work. Would it be hard to grind one of these HSS two-step 90 deg M8 bits 9/14 mm down to 8/14 mm? The hole is there already, I would just need a pilot.

Comment: Are you using cutting fluid? That might reduce the chatter. have you tried the lowest speed setting the press has?

Comment: Recommend you try a 4-fluted bit.

Answer (score 1):

If it **is not a wear problem of the drill, and you encounter the problem just with this particular material**, it might be  that you are operating at a frequency which favours resonance  and oscillations.

***Can you try increasing the rpms or lowering it and see if the vibrations are less?***

If that is the case you can attach some more mass (with a vice ) on the plate  (an inertia block if you like) to lower the natural frequency. That combined with an increase of rpm might solve your problem.

Comment: I would need to change the position of the transmission belt. I will try it and tell if it worked.

Comment: I agree the basic cause of the problem is that the drill bit is not cutting. It seems to be tearing at the material rather than cutting it. Whether that is caused by a blunt drill, or the wrong speed or down pressure, is a guess.

Comment: I agree it's difficult to do a proper "debugging" without a lot of information. Hopefully. Doubling the rpm might show significant improvement in vibration. Otherwise, the material might be too hard for the drill bit.